# Running Linux commands using python script

Tags: python, linux, shell

I am working on a python script which execute basic shell commands. like -

- check out a shell file from server - ct co -nc file_name
- set an environment variable in shell terminal - setenv variable value
- check in a file into server - ct ci -nc file_name.

Basically I want to know how to execute basic commands through python script.
Also can anyone help me to understand is there any way to source .cshrc (source file_name.cshrc) file which have basic shell commands like above through python script?

Following is the sample code I follow -

```
import sys
import subprocess
file_name = sys.argv[0]
print ("file name is ==>", file_name)
cmd = ['ct co -nc file_name']
time = subprocess.Popen (cmd, shell=True)
output,err = time.communicate()
print(output)
```

Error:

```
('given file name is ==>', 'script_test_sys.py')
/bin/sh: ct: command not found
None
```

Comment: all arguments in `['ct co -nc file_name']` should be comma separated like this 
`['ct', 'co', '-nc', 'file_name']`  or directly pass string as command `cmd = 'ct co -nc file_name'`

Comment: Avoid using `shell=True` unless you absolutely have to... it opens up all sorts of problems, and most of the time it's not needed.

Comment: Use the full path to the ct command

Answer (score 0):

all arguments in `['ct co -nc file_name']` should be comma separated like this

```
cmd = ['ct', 'co', '-nc', 'file_name']
```

or directly pass the string as a command

```
cmd = 'ct co -nc file_name'
```

Comment: hi,
Thank you for the response. I have figured out the way it works. 

import sys
import subprocess
cmd = ['cleartool co -nc file_name'] 
time = subprocess.Popen (cmd, shell=True) 
output,err = time.communicate()
print(output)